# Using a resource image name as a listbox list item C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to produce a list in a listbox using C# in VS2012, the idea is to click on one of many picture boxes which contain images stored as resources, as the different boxes are clicked, I want the action event to add the name property as a list item in the ListBox.

I got it to add the string System.drawing.bitmap using :

```
    private void PB1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
  {
     LB1.Items.Add(PB1.Image.ToString());               
  }
```

and

```
   private void PB1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
  {
     LB1.Items.Add(Properties.Resources.wrist1.ToString());           
  }
```

But I can't seem to find an access to the Object property 'Name'. I tried wrist1.GetPropertyItem(Name)  but it throws an error and will only accept an int.

any ideas anyone???

Answer (score 1):

```
private void PB1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
LB1.Items.Add(this.Name);
}
```

And name each PictureBox properly. ?

Comment: Doesn't work, that returns Form 1. not the name of the resourse picture.

The properties section of the resource image only has 1 attribute which is Name but I can't figure how to harvest the attribute value.